# Ajuda com rotacionamento(Quaternion.Slarp) no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Quero fazer meu objeto girar 120 graus e definir um tempo para isso. porém ao invés de girar 120 graus ele vai para o grau 120. Como arrumar isso?

```
Transform inicial;
float tempo;
float angle;
void Start () {
    inicial = GetComponent<Transform>();
    tempo = 2.0f * Time.deltaTime; // Aki era pra ser 2 segundos
     angle = inicial.rotation.z + 120;


}

void Update () {

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(inicial.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0,0, angle), tempo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Primeiro erro: mal uso de Slerp

Primeiramente, você não deve ter lido com atenção a documentação da função [Quaternion.Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) e por isso não entendeu corretamente como funciona o terceiro parâmetro. Essa função faz uma [interpolação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o) entre dois valores `a` e `b` (os dois primeiros parâmetros) de acordo com o *progresso* `t` (o terceiro parâmetro). Esse progresso precisar ser **necessariamente** um valor entre 0 e 1, tanto que na própria documentação está escrito que ele é truncado (*clamped*) para esse intervalo se for diferente dele (o negrito é meu):

> *Spherically interpolates between a and b by t. **The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]**.*

Em tradução livre:

> Interpola esfericamente entre os valores a e b por uma taxa t. O parâmetro t é truncado/mantido no intervalo [0, 1].

No seu código, o valor `a` é a rotação **atual** do objeto (observe o negrito - voltarei a falar disso de novo na próxima seção desta resposta), o valor `b` é a rotação desejada de 120 graus no eixo Z, e o valor `t` é um valor baixo (mais próximo de 0, talvez algo como 0.4), porque você multiplicou 2.0 pelo tempo de duração do último frame do jogo quando o seu código iniciou.

Ilustrando: uma interpolação entre `a=1` e `b=10`, por exemplo, resultaria em 1 se você usasse `t=0` e resultaria em 10 se você usasse `t=1`. E resultaria nos valores intermediários (2, 2.5, 4, 7.358, 9, 9.99, 9.999, ...) interpolados se você utilizasse qualquer valor de `t` entre 0 e 1. Funciona da mesma forma para as rotações. Se você utilizar `t=0` ele vai retornar o valor de `inicial.rotation`, e se você utilizar `t=1` ele vai retornar o valor de `Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle)`, e para qualquer `t` entre 0 e 1 ele vai retornar um valor intermediário entre essas duas rotações.

No seu código você usou um valor de `t` mais ou menos como 0.4, que foi calculado uma única vez lá no começo do jogo. Logo a sua rotação vai ser sempre o valor interpolado entre as duas rotações, lá nuns 40% a partir do primeiro valor (claro, considerando que é uma interpolação esférica e não linear). Vc altera esse mesmo valor a cada quadro, mas o `t` é sempre o mesmo, logo o seu objeto deveria rotacionar uma vez (pulando imediatamente para aquela rotação) e não rodar mais. Ele ainda roda um pouco por causa do seu segundo erro...

### Segundo erro: usar como rotação inicial a rotação atual

A cada quadro você interpola usando `a=inicial.rotation`. Essa não é a rotação inicial do seu objeto quando você começa o jogo (que é o que eu suponho que você desejava, já que está animando com interpolação), mas sim *a rotação atual após a execução do quadro anterior*! Logo, mesmo com você utilizando um valor de `t` fixo a cada quadro, o resultado vai variar um pouco porque a interpolação do quadro seguinte não vai ser mais entre `a` e `b` originais, mas entre `a+<resultado anterior>` e `b`.

### Solução

A solução é resolver os dois problemas anteriormente descritos.

Começando pelo último, é simples: salve a rotação inicial em um atributo da classe, e use-o sempre na chamada de Slerp. Assim vc garante que o seu `a` vai ser sempre o mesmo.

Movendo para o primeiro problema: calcule um valor de `t` que seja uma progressão de fato, ou seja, um valor entre 0 e 1. Como você quer usar tempo, defina um atributo da classe para contar o tempo você mesmo (somando o time.Deltatime nele a cada quadro) e pondere o valor de `t` calculando como o percentual de tempo decorrido (matemática simples, só fazendo ser tempo decorrido dividido pelo tempo total, isso já te dá um valor entre 0 e 1).

Do ponto de vista de desempenho, você não precisa mais calcular a interpolação uma vez que a animação tiver acabado (isto é, o valor de `t` tiver chegado a 1). Por isso, coloque isso dentro de um `if`.

Exemplo de código:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

    Transform inicial;
    float tempo;
    float angle;
    float decorrido;
    Quaternion start;
    Quaternion end;

    void Start () {
        inicial = GetComponent<Transform>();
        tempo = 2.0f; // 2 segundos
        decorrido = 0.0f;
        angle = inicial.rotation.z + 180;
        start = inicial.rotation;
        end = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
    }

    void Update () {
        if(decorrido <= tempo) {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(start, end, decorrido / tempo);
            decorrido += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

> P.S.: Eu deixei assim para você perceber só o que realmente precisava mudar para funcionar. Mas note que você não precisa capturar e guardar a transformação do objeto atual em `inicial` porque ele já está em `transform`. Isto é, no contexto deste código, `inicial.rotation` é a mesma coisa que `transform.rotation`.